# Select MySQL rows regardless of a column's data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that selects either males, females, or both sex from my database.

Function looks like:

```
function getMembers($sex = null) {

    if (is_null($sex)) {
        $sex = (0 || 1);
    }

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE sex = :sex");
    $query->execute(array(
        ':sex' => $sex
    ));

    $members_results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I call the query like that:

getMembers(0); (fetches the girls fine)

getMembers(1); (fetches the guys fine)

getMembers(); (fetches only the guys)

I believe the $sex = (0 || 1); line is wrong.

How would you fix it?
Thanks

Ps.: My query actually looks like:

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT picture_path, profile_picture, username, last_visit, signup_date, settings, sex FROM tusers 
                WHERE profile_picture IS NOT NULL
                AND settings LIKE '1,%' 
                AND sex = :sex
                AND  last_visit BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 DAY AND CURDATE() 
                AND signup_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY 
                ORDER BY RAND()
                LIMIT 15");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but you should get the point.

(Actually it would be more practical to split the query string in several parts - mixing in needed columns, values, wheres and bindings by if/loop/whatever.)

```
<?php

function getMembers($sex = null) {

    if (is_null($sex)) {
      $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users;");
      $query->execute();
    }
    else {
      $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE sex = :sex;");
      $query->execute(array(':sex' => $sex));
    }
    $members_results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. I pasted what my query actually looks like. As you can see it's quite long and the code would get repetitive. If I don't find anything soon though I'll use this logic.

Comment: Well, you have to ... how should that work automagically for all kinds of SQL statements?

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm using. Still clean.

Answer (score 1):

The line `$sex = (0 || 1);` is executed by PHP so `$sex` will contains `1`. You can not to proceed this way because your final string will be `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE sex = 1"`

Try something like *djot* suggested

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create three functions separately like:

```
function getMaleMembers()
function getFemaleMembers()
function getAllMembers()
```

and place a different mysql_query for each of them..like for example:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE sex = '1'");
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE sex = '0'");
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users");
```

This will be quite easy to implement and makes more sense.

Comment: That's what I had before but each function used like 50 lines of code. I think I got something neat now, getMembers('female'), getMembers('male'), getMembers();

Answer (score 0):

(0 || 1) means 0 OR 1 and will return 1 every single time. Full answer is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php#43111

For your desired functionality, your code should be:

```
function getMembers($sex = null) {

    if (is_null($sex)) {
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users");
        $query->execute();
    } else {
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE sex = :sex");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':sex' => $sex
        ));
    }
    $members_results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```